# Directly converting a range of numeral entries to text with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge list, which I have to work on each day. I want to change my reference columns data from number to text so it enables me to do some advanced filtering and referencing futures. I don't want to add any new column and for instance, use `Text()` function in excel as this range is same in different files I have to concatenate and link. I am just wondering if it is possible to do that in place with a VBA code or not. I tried:

```
selection=selection.text
```

or doing some paste special efforts with ', empty cells and converting to array back and forth but not succeded. Any idea? I also don't want to do a loop as I need to this effort for several files which I can't manipulate their structure or change them with my weak laptop each time every day!

Regards,
M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use built-in Excel functionality *Text-to-columns*.
If you want it automated using VBA, try this:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("B1", "B4").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("B1"), _
                                     DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                     FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
End With
```

Above converts all numbers in the range B1:B4 in sheet1.
The `FieldInfo` argument identifies the conversion.
We use `Array(1,2)` which means we want to convert column 1 to text.
Check [*Text to columns*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel) functionality to understand it further. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out. It converts a a range of values into text format

```
Sub Convert_To_Text()
    Dim vData As Variant
    vData = Range("A1:D1")
    Range("A1:D1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1:D1") = vData
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, as I expressed in my post I already tried this method but not working. I again tried your code. Just by changing the cell type you cant convert the data type itself. I even added a clear function and tried to write it in other range, not working at all. Anyhow thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @l42 answer and point here is what I was needed... and came to

```
Sub NumbtoText()

If Not ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then Selection.TextToColumns _
                                    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                    FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Thanks